# MvvmCross Windows Store App - Testing suspend/resume (tombstoning)

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, mvvmcross, suspend, tombstoning

I'm trying to test "tombstoning" in my C# Store app that is based on mvvmcross. I've based my code on [Stuart's instructions](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/v3-new-viewmodel-lifecycle.html).

```
    public class SavedState
    {
        public int EntityId { get; set; }
    }

    public void ReloadState(SavedState savedState)
    {
        _entityId = savedState.EntityId;
    }

    public SavedState SaveState()
    {
        var state = new SavedState();
        state.EntityId = _appStateService.SelectedEntity.ID;
        return state;
    }
```

"ReloadState" is never called, no matter what I do on my local machine, or in the simulator. Is there any way to trigger suspension while the debugger is running? How do people test this functionality?

Comment: Are you sure you've added an event for `Suspending` and `Resuming`? If so, would you mind adding them?

Comment: For win8.1 does https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/550 help?

Comment: Stuart - that does help. I'll try again and update this accordingly.

Comment: Nate: thanks for the suggestion - will check out info provided by Stuart and respond re events, etc. here.

Comment: Hi Steve, I have the same issue, but I can't understand how to use the Stuart' suggestion.
Could you please post the solution, if any?